# Backbone fetch returns all instance of my model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following code which should fetch one object in my model and render it with a template :

```
 productDetails: function (id) {
        var product = new app.models.Product({id: id});
        product.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                app.slider.slidePage(new app.views.ProductView({model: data}).render().$el);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, for some reason, `data` is a list of all my model objects :

```
attributes: Object
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
10: Object
11: Object
12: Object
13: Object
...
id: "73"
```

I am new to Backbone so I have no clue what could cause this...

Do you need more code?

ProductModel.js

```
app.models.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
    },

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        if (method === "read") {
            app.adapters.product.findById(parseInt(this.id)).done(function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            });
        }
    }

});

app.models.ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: app.models.Product,

    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        if (method === "read") {
app.adapters.product.findByName(options.data.name).done(function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you have data referred to as a global variable or one that is in a higher scope? You might be referring to the wrong data.

Comment: On second thought, your adapters.product is probably referring to the collection and then returning the collection in your Product synch function.

Comment: @DaveC, you were right. My `findById` function inside my adapter was returning `products` instead of the `product` found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `adapters.product` is probably referring to the collection and then returning the collection in your Product `sync` function.

The solution would be something like this:

```
var findById = function (id) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var product = null;
  var l = products.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (products[i].id === id) {
      product = products[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  deferred.resolve(product);   // HERE WAS product__s__
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You could have at least been a little imaginative with the given solution ;-)

Comment: No yours was perfect - I'm lazy and would much rather copy yours :)